How can we be sure that the triangle inequality works in this case?

Consider two complex numbers $z$ and $w$ such that $|z| = |w| = 3$ and $|z - w| = 3\sqrt{2}.$ What is the minimum value of $P = |z + 1 + i| + |w - 2 + 5i|$?

This is a question from our country's university entrance exam. Here's the solution:
On the complex plane $Oxy$, let $A$ and $B$ be the points representing $z$ and $w.$ It's clear that A and B lie on the circle with center $O(0;0)$ and radius $3.$ $AB = 3\sqrt{2}$ so $△OAB$ is a right triangle at $O,$ so $w = iz$ or $w = -iz.$ (The proof of this result is non-trivial but I decided to skip it to focus on the main question.)
• Case $01: w = iz$
$P = |z + 1 + i| + |iz - 2 + 5i| = |z + 1 + i| + |i||z + \frac{-2 + 5i}{i}| = |z + 1 + i| + |z + 5  + 2i| = |z + 1 + i| + |-z - 5 - 2i| \geq |-4 - i| = \sqrt{17}$
(By the triangle inequality)
• Case $02: w = -iz$
$P = |z + 1 + i| + |-iz - 2 + 5i| = |z + 1 + i| + |i||-z + \frac{-2 + 5i}{i}| = |z + 1 + i| + |-z + 5  + 2i| \geq |6 + 3i| = 3\sqrt{5}$
Combining two cases, we have $P_{min} = \sqrt{17}$

To my understanding, the equality only occurs when the two vectors point in the same direction. For example, in case $01$, the vector representing $(z + 1 + i)$ and the vector representing $(-z - 5 - 2i)$ must be able to point in the same direction. How can we be so sure that this is the case? For example, as $OAB$ is a right triangle, $\vec{OA}$ and $\vec{OB}$ could never point in the same direction, so we could not say the minimum value of $|\vec{OA}| + |\vec{OB}|$ is $|\vec{OA} + \vec{OB}|.$ What about the two vectors representing $(z + 1 + i)$ and $(-z - 5 - 2i)$ that indicates they can align in the same direction?
Thank you!

Why do you think OA and OB need to be in the same direction for the triangle inequality to suffice?

@Gwen Isn't it the triangle inequality? $|\vec{OA} + \vec{OB}|$ can only be equal to $|\vec{OA}| + |\vec{OB}|$ when $\vec{OA} = k\vec{OB}$ for some non-negative $k$. Afaik, this is equivalent to $OA + AB \geq OB$ and the equality only occurs when $A \in OB$ in synthetic geometry.

To clarify, the solution claims that the equality in the triangle inequality does occur, so my question wasn't  really whether the triangle inequality no longer holds in this situation but more like how do we know for certain that the equality could indeed occur.

@Gwen Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems you're mistaking the triangle inequality for some other inequality. Afaik, the equality in the triangle inequality does not necessitate that $z_1 = z_2$ but only that the vectors representing them point in the same direction.

No no, you aren't. I was trying to understand your question. Check my answer once. Hope I'll be clear

I edited my answer to show a general format. It's still pretty hard to remember. So simple process is kind of better. Which exam are you preparing for?

@Gwen Thanks, it does seem more efficient to just calculate the discriminant on demand than memorizing the general form. It's the Vietnamese National High School Exam for university admissions.

You can follow the last line in my answer which I edited just now. That will be easy to memorise and helpful ;) also usually you don't get that complicated questions for mcqs

If I didn't understand your problem wrongly, then youre trying to find when equality does occur.
$|z_1+z_2|=|z_1|+|z_2|$ can only occur when $z_2$ is a scalar multiple of $z_1$. In your case,
$$(z + 1 + i)=k(-z - 5 - 2i)$$
$$\implies (k+1)z=(-5k-1)-i(2k+1)$$
$$\implies z=\frac{-(5k+1)}{k+1}-i\frac{i(2k+1)}{k+1}$$
$$|z|=3 \implies \frac{(-(5k+1))^2+(-(2k+1))^2}{(k+1)^2}=9$$
$$\implies 25k^2+10k+1+4k^2+4k+1=9k^2+18k+9$$
$$\implies 20k^2-4k-7=0$$
Discriminant $(16)-4×-7×20>0$, thus $k$ does exist. Hence equality occurs. In the replies I was trying to make sense of your question, I'm sorry :)
More generally, if $$u=az+b,v=cz+d,u,b,d,z\in \mathbb{C},a,c\in\mathbb{R}$$, and $|u|+|v|=|u+v|$, then
$$az+b=k(cz+d)\implies z(a-kc)=kd-b $$
Mind that $(a-kc)$ is a scalar value (real).
$$z=\frac{1}{a-kc}((kx_d-x_b)+i(ky_d-y_b))$$
Thus $$|z|^2=\frac{(kx_d-x_b)^2+(ky_d-y_b)^2}{(a-kc)^2}$$
Here we know all values except $k$.
$$|z|^2(a^2+k^2c^2-2akc)=k^2(x_d^2+y_d^2)-2k(x_dx_b+y_dy_b)+(x_b^2+y_b^2)$$
Finally,
$$k^2(x_d^2+y_d^2-c^2|z|^2)-2k(x_dx_b+y_dy_b-ac|z|^2)+(x_b^2+y_b^2-|z|^2a^2)=0$$
The discriminant, after simplifying, will be written as
$$(x_dx_b+y_dy_b-ac|z|^2)^2≥{(x_b^2+y_b^2-|z|^2a^2)(x_d^2+y_d^2-c^2|z|^2)}$$
Thus for $u=az+b,v=cz+d$, for them to satisfy $|u|+|v|=|u+v|$, we must get
$$(Re(b\overline d)-ac|z|^2)^2≥(|b|^2-|z|^2a^2)(|d|^2-|z^2|c^2)$$
you can just usually check the RHS, as most of the times it comes negative, which is always less than a whole square.

Thanks a lot! This does look like an excellent way to verify it! The issue, however, is that this is a multiple-choice question that the test taker in practice only has about 3-5 minutes to solve. Figuring out how to solve it already consumes some time, so I wonder if there's some quick way to know that the vectors could indeed align in the same direction without going through too much manipulation. Thanks again!
